# How to Copy data with block ctrl+copy from datawindow to Excel

Tags: excel, copy, copy-paste, powerbuilder, datawindow

please help me how to Copy data from datawindow with methode block data then ctrl+C into Excel or clipboard, thank you for help.

Herman

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom right corner of your data window.

You'd find Column Specification, Data and Control list. Click on Data and retrieve it. Once retrieved, click on where I drew a red pointer, you can click SHIFT key to include the other rows.. You should be able to block copy that way

[Picture here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwpA.png)

Hope this helps

Tem.